# Which power factor is better in an industry -0.21 or -0.94 and why?

Tags: power, power-factor-correction

In the electrical panels , when i switched on-off the capacitor bank then 
power factor gets shifted from

0.89(lagging/during OFF condition) to -0.87(leading/during ON condition)    ,

similarly on switching on-off the capacitor bank power factor shifted from 0.87(lagging/during OFF condition) to -0.31(leading/during ON condition)

Now i want to know which power factor transition is better 0.89 to -0.87 or 0.87 to -0.31  and why ??[image]

Comment: You have made a [duplicate post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/359550/which-power-factor-is-better-0-21-or-0-94-and-why). You should have fixed your other question instead of creating a second one. Delete one of them. Also explain the meter readings. What are the first two lines?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which power factor is better -0.21 or -0.94 and why?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/359550/which-power-factor-is-better-0-21-or-0-94-and-why)

Comment: Rather then focussing on that post , can someone please answer to this question 